# IIS7 install two SSL certificates to two different host (not subdomains)

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, ssl, https

My question is very similar to this one: [IIS 7.0 install two SSL certificates with two different host headers](https://serverfault.com/questions/207459/iis-7-0-install-two-ssl-certificates-with-two-different-host-headers) except that my domains are totally different:

1 SSL for http://domain1.com
1 SSL for http://domain2.com

I installed my certificates as described in that question/answer but if I navigate do domain2.com (which I binded via appcmd ...) I get the certificate for domain1.com. Therefor if I open the bindings via IIS7 I see that domain2.com use the wrong certificate, but if I change it will change for domain1.com too.

I really don't know how to solve this issue!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  An SSL certificate applies to a whole port/ip combination because the host header is encrypted so can't be used at that stage.

The question you refer to suggests to apply a single wildcard certificate to both domains because the single certificate is relevant to both domains.  The option allows a single certificate to be applied to multiple sites.  Where the domains are entirely different this won't work.  You are trying to apply multiple certificates.

If you have two seperate domains that you want to use SSL on then you will need two seperate IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this with a [multi domain certificate](http://www.whichssl.com/mdc.html). These are usually more expensive than regular certificates but allow you to add multiple totally different domain names to a single certificate.

Answer (score 0):

If the web server is behind a load balancer it would make sense to run the https element on a non-standard port and redirect it using said load balancer. This will allow you to run multiple certificates.